# Display validation error messages (Spring Boot, Angular CLI 7)

Tags: angular, spring, forms, validation

I'am trying to display errors passed from backend (Spring Boot) to frontend (Angular CLI 7). Errors are passed on by the ResponseEntity.

I have a function that check for response

```
    OnRegister(user) {
      this.errorMessages = [];
      this.authenticationService.register(user)
      .subscribe(resp => {
          this.router.navigateByUrl('/pages/authentication/login');
        }, error => this.errorMessages.push(error.error)
      );
      console.log(this.errorMessages);
    }
```

Array errorMessages hold "ValidationMessage" objects - fields: field, message.

Console output:

```
[]
  0: Array(3)
    0: {field: "password", message: "Field password cannot be null."}
    1: {field: "passwordConfirm", message: "Field passwordConfirm cannot be null."}
    2: {field: "email", message: "Field email cannot be null."}
```

How can i get an element from this array.

It's not possible to use just:

```
<li *ngFor="let error of errorMessages">
  <p>{{error.message}}</p>
</li>
```

Comment: can you try this.errorMessages.push(error.error[0])

Comment: It will add just 1 element to my array. Now they're all added, but I can not read them.

Comment: I mean what i think for console output is that you are getting array of array. i.e `error.error` returns an array. Can you check?

Comment: Checked and got this: `[]
  0:
    field: "email"
    message: "Field email cannot be null.`

Comment: can you try `*ngFor="let error of errorMessages[0]"`

Comment: Error: "Cannot read property '0' of undefined".

Comment: can you do `.subscribe(resp => {
          this.router.navigateByUrl('/pages/authentication/login');
        }, error => {this.errorMessages.push(error.error); console.log('myerror:', error.error)}
      );`
bcz i think your `console.log(this.errorMessages)` should be an empty array coz its outside async function

Comment: Solution - `error => this.errorMessages = error.error.map(x => Object.assign({}, x))` - copy error objects to array (without push).

Comment: errorMessages wasn't NULL, the problem was that array containted another array:) Thank you for help:)

Answer (score 0):

You need to iterate the message from spring into the string[] state named error.

```
error: (error: (any)) => {
          let errors = error.error.errors;
          for (let i = 0; i < errors.length; i++) {
            this.error.push(errors[i].field + " " + errors[i].message);
          }
        }
```

And then, you can show them in the your component html like this

```
<div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">
   <ul>
      <li *ngFor="let error of error">{{error}}</li>
   </ul>
</div>
```